# fazer um select agrupando por ano

Tags: mysql, sql, select

tenho um campo cliente
nele eu preciso fazer um count de quantos clientes foram cadastrado durante os anos de 2016, 2017 e 2018

eu estava fazendo 3 select, sendo que em cada um eu fazia um where dataCadastro >= 2016-01-01 and dataCadastro <= 2016-12-31

só que está muito lento, pois ele roda 3 select

é possivel fazer um select só, agrupando por ano essa informação?

Comment: Olá tentei efetuar a busca dessa forma e esta retornando uma mensagem de erro, alguém poderia me ajudar? SQL: select datapedido, sum(total) total from pedido where status>0 group by substr(datapedido,0,7) order by datapedido desc Erro: select datapedido, sum(total) total from pedido where status>0 group by substr(datapedido,0,7) order by datapedido desc LIMIT 0, 25
Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'servidor.pedido.datapedido' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS QTD_CLIENTES_CADASTRADOS, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATACADASTRO) AS ANO
  FROM TABELA  
 WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATACADASTRO) IN (2016, 2017, 2018)
 GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATACADASTRO);
```

**Explicação:**
Ao utilizar a função `EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE)`você irá extrair o dia/mês/ano de um determinando campo `timestamp` do seu banco de dados, com esta função, você pode fazer condicionais, utilizar no `order by`, adicionar no `SELECT` entre outras funcionalidades.

Utilizei o `in` para evitar que sejam adicionados três `and` (que seriam referentes a cada ano), evitando assim o `SQL` grande sem necessidade.

**Editado**

Há outra forma de fazer esse `SQL` evitando tantos `EXTRACTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(S.QTD) AS CLIENTES_CADASTRADOS, S.ANO
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS QTD, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATACADASTRO) AS ANO
          FROM TABELA) AS S
 WHERE S.ANO IN (2016, 2017, 2018);
 GROUP BY S.ANO;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Se as datas estiverem em campos do tipo date ou datetime, poderá usar [**YEAR**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

YEAR ( date ) - Retorna um inteiro que representa o ano da date especificada.

```
SELECT COUNT(coluna), YEAR(dataCadastro) FROM tabela GROUP BY YEAR(dataCadastro);
```

**Exemplo:**

Tabela

[image: Tabela]

Resultado  `SELECT COUNT(id), YEAR(dataCadastro) FROM tabela2 GROUP BY YEAR(dataCadastro);`

[image: select]

> Se o campo `dataCadastro` for do tipo varchar, primeiro tem que converter para o formato date utilizando a função  [**STR_TO_DATE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), depois podes usar a função YEAR.  `YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(dataCadastro, "%Y-%m-%d"))`

Answer (score 0):

Se o YEAR está no formato date então podes usar a SUBSTRING do MySql

> SELECT count(*) as total , SUBSTRING(ano, 1,4)
>   FROM `cliente`
>   GROUP by SUBSTRING(ano, 1,4)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]